# MS VC++ how to build DLL without requiring vc redist

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to build a simple .Net wrapper around some basic C++ code.

The C++ code does not rely on anything in the vcredist dlls, so I'm wondering if I can setup my project, so it doesn't require those dlls to work ?

I'd hate to have my users download and run vcredist, just for a simple DLL to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to link your DLL with the "Use the CRT as a static library" option:

Project properties / Configuration / C/C++ / Code Generation / Runtime library / Multithreaded (ie. **not** any of the "DLL" options).

Comment: This seems like the right approach, however when I set it to /MT it complains that this is incompatible with /clr - which I presume is necessary to build the .Net class (the wrapper for the native C++ class)

Comment: Ah, that's probably true.  But if your users need .Net, is it reasonable to assume they'll also have the relevant CRT DLLs?

Comment: Well they'll obviously have the CRT DLLs, it's the MSVCR90.DLL and similar I'm worried about - the VC++ specific stuff.

If I try to run an application using this DLL as it is, it'll complain about not finding MSVCR90.DLL :-( (Unless you've installed vcredist or visual studio)

Comment: MSVCR90.DLL *is* the CRT DLL... you'll probably find you're OK without doing anything. The thing to do would be to set up a clean Windows VM, install the known prerequisites of your software (.Net and whatever else it needs) and then try your DLL - it'll probably just work.

Comment: Ok my bad about what is the CRT DLL - what I meant was the ordinary .Net stuff (mscorlib and so forth).

I'm installing a clean Windows VM as I write, and will let you know whether it works or not.

It's just in the past I've always had to install vcredist to run anything compiled with VC++.

Anyway I'll keep you informed :-)

Comment: I've tried it out now, and it actually works on a clean VM. So I guess the solution is simply to not worry about it :-)

Comment: Great! My favourite kind of problem is the one that isn't there. 8-)