# Statically link to the dll files

Tags: dll, static-linking

I have already built a project, and run it in VS2010.

But if I want to run the .exe on other computers which does not
install Visual Studio, it will need .dll files (such as msvcrt.dll and
msvcp60.dll in WINDOWS\SYSTEM32, and some other dlls in the
development package). I didn't use MFC in this project. How to static
link all these dlls into the .exe file in Visual C++ so that I don't
have to copy all the dlls to the other machines?

BTW: I don't want to make install package either

Thanks
Siba

Answer (score 0):

You can set your project to statically link the CRT, by using the /MT flag for the [runtime library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=VS.100).aspx). Or, you could keep the /MD setting, and install the vcredist package along with your executable (you can get it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555), and also from one of your VS2010 installation folders). To get an idea of each options pros and cons, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757418/should-i-compile-with-md-or-mt).

Oh, and [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149531/ms-vc-how-to-build-dll-without-requiring-vc-redist) has been asked before...